# How to convert data in hexadecimal to IEEE 754 format float value in swift

Tags: ios, swift, math, ieee-754

The input is [0x41,0xa7,0x33,0x33] -> is a UInt8 array. When I tried using the algorithm for IEEE 754 by splitting into sign, exponential and mantissa, I stuck in the middle due to the power function returns NaN for the pow(2,(exp - 1023)) part.

Is there any easy built in methods available for swift?

Comment: Is that array `big-endian` or `little-endian` representation of `Float`? Or in other way is your number `4.18288e-08` or `20.9`?